# How to read .RData files from .NET (without R)?

Tags: c#, r, .net

How to read .RData files from .NET?

Solutions provided to similar questions automate R to open an .Rdata file and return the data. The recommended way to do it in .NET would be to use the R.NET library, which is designed for fast data exchange with R.

But is there any way to read the .RData file from .NET without having R installed on the machine?

Answer (score 1):

R.NET might still be the best way to go as it can be used without having R installed.

From the [R.NET library GitHub page](https://github.com/rdotnet/rdotnet):

> R needs not necessarily be installed as a software on the executing
> machine, so long as DLL files are accessible (you may need to tweak
> environment variables for the latter to work, though)

Note: R is provided under GPL 3 license, which mean that if you embed its DLL in a commercial .NET application, the source code of your application must be open:

> You can distribute your application using a GPL library commercially,
> but you must also provide the source code.

> If you distribute this library in an executable, you must disclose your source code by
> providing it either alongside your distribution or list an accessible
> way (URL, physical copy) to obtain the source for 3 years. Does not
> apply if you serve through a web portal.